# in angular when i hit npm start it gives error like this

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:806:20)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:676:19)
    at ../web-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:50:21
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exports.sendMessageToMaster (../web-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:45:16)
    at ../web-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/worker.js:103:66
    at step (../web-app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.throw (../web-app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at rejected (../web-app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:24194) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24194) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i was migrating from angular 8 to angular 9,
i changed my package json anf npm packages according to angular 9,but still getting this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.